# Can't make the draggable to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag

I have a code on jsfiddle that I can't get it to work, I have all the functions working except draggable. When I add `$(init)` the deal button stops working and I can not get it to deal cards, once I remove `$(init)` it works but doesn't drag. Can someone please help me to figure it out how to make draggable work? Thank you.

My JsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/otpspbhs/

```js
$('#deal').click(function () {
    dealCard(randomCard());
});

function init() {
  $('.drop').droppable( {
    drop: handleDropEvent
  }); 
}

var cardsInDeck = new Array();
var numberOfCardsInDeck = 5;
cardsInDeck[0] = "AceHearts";
cardsInDeck[1] = "Clubs2";
cardsInDeck[2] = "ClubsAce";
cardsInDeck[3] = "DiamondsKing";
cardsInDeck[4] = "SpadesJack";

function dealCard(i) {
    if (numberOfCardsInDeck == 0) return false;
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "https://cop4813eaglin.pbworks.com/f/" + cardsInDeck[i] + ".png";

    document.body.appendChild(img);
    removeCard(i);
}

function randomCard() {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfCardsInDeck);  
}
 function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
  var draggable = ui.draggable;
  $('#drop').html( 'The card with ID "' + draggable.attr('id') + '" was dropped onto me!' );
    
 }

function removeCard(c)
{
    // simply make every higher numbered card move down 1
    for (j=c; j <= numberOfCardsInDeck - 2; j++)
    {
        cardsInDeck[j] = cardsInDeck[j+1];
    }
    numberOfCardsInDeck--;
}
```

```css
.drop {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #BC5347;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Deal Card" id="deal" />
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id='drop' class='drop'>Drop Here</div>
```

Comment: Deal button stops working when init function is called because you didn't include jquery ui on your jsfiddle. After that you should make your images draggable. You can find an example here: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, include jquery ui.

Second, make the images draggable after creating them:

```
function dealCard(i) {
    if (numberOfCardsInDeck == 0) return false;
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "https://cop4813eaglin.pbworks.com/f/" + cardsInDeck[i] + ".png";
    $(img).draggable();

    document.body.appendChild(img);
    removeCard(i);
}
```

Here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/otpspbhs/3/).

Comment: Great, thank you for your help, i was sticking the $(init); and draggable into a wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Drag and Drop Basic tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)

To make img draggable you must:

- set the draggable attribut to "true", I don't see where in the code you do this
- set the handle function of the drag event to be sure what data des you transfert on drag

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic , make the cards draggable and your box as droppable.
And adding more to it  ... use `.append` so that dragged card will be dropped and appended inside your box only